# CSS or jQuery to right align image in Viewport and still allow scrolling to left

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, alignment

I'm working on a HTML page for Webkit, and have an image wider than the viewport (2048 x 1536px). I'd like to have the right half of the image appear in the viewport as the starting point, and allow scrolling to the left to see the rest of the image.

I've tried a few things in CSS (float, negative margin offsets) without any luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html laneg="en">
<head>
<title>Viewport example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.44, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/> 
</head>
<body>
<img src="image25.jpg" width="4800" height="2400" />
</body>
</html>
```

Visual representation: http://i44.tinypic.com/351j1pw.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to force the browser to scroll. Scroll it by 4800px horizontally to make sure it's on the right on every device. Or just use the image's width instead of specifiying a number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.scrollTo(4800,0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.scroll(/* IMAGE WIDTH*/, 0)` in a JavaScript block.

e.g. `window.scroll(4800, 0)`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/bneqh/

Answer (score 0):

By default in a left to right world (*not arabic*), all web pages starting at the left side, allowing you to scroll to the right.

What you are asking is having a normal web page, starting from the left, and having a scrollbar which giving you the possibility to even scroll more to the left.

One solution for this is (*no JS*) setting the image as a background-image by CSS, position it to the right, and when the page grows (*viewport*), you will reveal more to the left from the image as the viewport increases

Otherwise you have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery sollution ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5MJN/8/)):

Add an ID to the image:

```
<img src="image25.jpg" id="theImage" width="4800" height="2400" />
```

Use [`scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/):

```
$(function() {
    $('body').scrollLeft($('#theImage').width());
});
```

Of course you can just use the width of 4800 insead of `width()`. But this is more dynamic if the image size would be variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS direction to change rendering from being left-to-right, to right-to-left.

[CSS direction property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp)

Here's a jsFiddle that shows this. Additionally, by wrapping the image in an outter

```
<div>
```

with overflow:hidden, you can limit what is shown on screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/vzZgc/